# Using one tab for all viewControllers in XLPagerTabStrip Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11

Is there any way by which we can switch to all the other view controller using Code

I am using XLPagerTabStrip Cocoapod for the tab views.
I am trying to make a switch case for all the child Views that I have implemented as UIStoryBoard.

Answer (score 1):

There is an array of view controllers on the base class `PagerTabStripViewController` - so rather than switching over the view controllers, you can just loop through the array.

See `viewControllers` in `PagerTabStripViewController` - this will be all the view controllers within the tabs.